# inequality proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

how could we show that the following holds for $k \ge 2$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$:
$$ 1 < \left( k - \frac{1}{2}\right) \log{\left(\frac{k}{k-1}\right)} $$
or equivalently, how can we show that
$$ e < \left( \frac{k}{k-1} \right)^{k-1/2} $$
Thanks!

Comment: @joriki Mine was incorrect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $k\ge2$,

$$
\begin{align}
\left(k-\frac12\right)\log\frac k{k-1}
&=
-\left(k-\frac12\right)\log\frac{k-1}k
\\
&=
-\left(k-\frac12\right)\log\left(1-\frac1k\right)
\\
&\gt
\left(k-\frac12\right)\left(\frac1k+\frac1{2k^2}+\frac1{3k^3}\right)
\\
&=
1+\frac1{12k^2}-\frac1{6k^3}
\\
&\ge1\;.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Quite interestingly, this version of the "usual" formulation of this problem (where $k$ replaced by $k+1$) leads to your simpler solution as the signs in the log series don't alternate any more.  Presented with the original problem I was unable to think of this shift so I've now learned a neat trick.

Comment: @Apin: You're welcome!

Answer (score 4):

An article on this problem appeared in the American Mathematical Monthly 2 years ago. It contains 3 proofs. The reference is:

> Amer. Math. Monthly 117 (2010) 273–277. doi:10.4169/000298910X480126

You can view the article [here](http://brage.bibsys.no/hsh/bitstream/URN%3aNBN%3ano-bibsys_brage_11956/1/khattri-Threeproof.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

1- Let k-1=u,

2- Show the function $(1+\frac{1}{u})^{u+\frac{1}{2}}$ is decreasing for $u\geq 1$,

3- Show the limit of this function when u goes to infinity is $e$,

4- Conclude.